# Excel formula how to avoid circular reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, circular-reference

I am trying to write a formula that will sum a column if the last row is at least row 4 or higher. I thought I could use `LOOKUP()` and `INDIRECT()` but there appears to be a problem that comes up when I delete values from the column.

At first when I put the formula in it works fine.

Formula:

```
=IF(LOOKUP(2,1/(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F)) >= 4, SUM(INDIRECT("F4:F" & LOOKUP(2,1/(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F)))), 0)
```

The 1st condition is check and does not = TRUE so set value to zero. That works as expected:

[image]

In the 2nd situation it runs as expected. Test condition if condition is TRUE then run the SUM with INDIRECT and LOOKUP:

[image]

However in the 3rd situation it fails to update or sometimes it gives me a `circular` error:

[image]

When an error comes up:

[image]

Now I do not understand why this error is showing up?

When recalculating I am assuming the formula starts with the IF statement and if that is the case then it should check the LOOKUP condition and if not true then set value to zero.

So why does this work until I remove all amounts from my column and is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: Minor comment:  Since `INDIRECT` is volatile, but `INDEX` is not, you might get slightly better performance if you replace `INDIRECT("F4:F" & LOOKUP(2,1/(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F)))` with `F4:INDEX(F:F,LOOKUP(2,1/--(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F)))`

Comment: I cannot repro your error, although I do get `#N/A` error if column F is empty except for the formula in F2.  Since you have text in F3, that should not happen in your situation.

Comment: are you able to share a sample set of data and indicate what you try to achieve on the sample?

Comment: @TerryW the data does not matter. I have a macro that add amounts to a column and I want that column to auto sum at the top

Comment: @Mike-SMT If you are able to provide sample data and exact steps, it will **greatly** help people to Recreate and Test the error (which [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/) has already told you they are unable to do).  That is the essence of a [mcve]